# Browse button not show file path in text box in java

Tags: java

I created a browse button and here is the code for that:

```
private void lookForExeClick () throws FileNotFoundException{

    DirectoryDialog dlg = new DirectoryDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell());
    String directoryPath = dlg.open();
    //File file = new File(directoryPath, "MyFileName.txt");
    //FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

My text box that I created on the gui is this:

```
    exeLocationText = new Text(controlGroupForSingleRun, SWT.BORDER);
    exeLocationText.setText("");
    data = new GridData();
    data.widthHint = 265;
    exeLocationText.setLayoutData(data);
```

How do I get the filepath that I choose in the directory dialog box after I click browse into the text box that I created in java.  Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: `exeLocationText.setText(directoryPath)`?

Comment: You are asking a question about classes outside of standard java. Please either share the librar(y/ies) you are using by updating the question or the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, you would just have:

```
String directoryPath = dlg.open();
if(directoryPath != null)
  exeLocationText.setText(directoryPath);
```